# Andoid Nexus 5X Microphone sound too low

Tags: nexus-5x, 7.1-nougat

Recently, about 4 weeks ago, the volume on my microphone became too low for listeners. I can hear them perfectly though.

I found somewhere on the internet (I can't remember where) that if I clear the system cache (see below), then the volume returns to normal. Which it did.

It's happened again though. So I've cleared the cache again and again the microphone volume has returned to normal.

Is there a way around this? It looks like its a software fault rather than a hardware fault.

These are the instructions I followed to wipe the cache:

- Power off the phone
- Hold down power and the volume down button
- Use the volme up/down to select "Recovery mode" and press power button
- When "No command" is displayed, hold down power and press volume up.
- Select wipe cache
- Restart

Currently on 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

### Your problem root is the "Noise Cancelling" feature.

These are the possible replies for your question :

- Disable Noise cancelling feature **[ROOT ONLY]**.
- Put a little piece of tape on your Noise Canceling Microphone.
- Use Headset or Bluetooth Microphone.
- Wait for an OTA Update (Hopfully it will resolve your issue).